# Sending Variables to a REST api to be saved on server

Tags: android, rest, post, httprequest, put

I am really struggling with this for some time now and I am really lost in terms of how this works.

I have written a REST service in netbeans and I have passed through Json data and tested that it works using Postman and it is successfully saving to the database.

Now, I want the variables in my mobile application to be sent to that REST api so that they can then be saved to the database.

I have looked at many answers on this but can get none which fully explain to me how to do this.. Ideally I am trying to POST or PUT data from my mobile app into my database.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            details = editTextDetails.getText().toString();
            getCurrentDateandTime();

            String url = "http://localhost:8080/engAppApi/webservices/engineerTable/";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

            try {
                params.put("machinetype", machineType);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                params.put("workordernumber", workOrderNumber);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("employeename", employee);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("activity", activity);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("durationhours", durationHours);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("durationmins", durationMins);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("downtimehours", downTimeHours);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("downtimemins", downTimeMins);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                params.put("details", details);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                params.put("currentdateandtime", currentDateandTime);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            StringEntity jsonEntity = null;
            try {
                jsonEntity = new StringEntity(params.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            request = new HttpPost(url);

            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


            request.setEntity(jsonEntity);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

can someone please point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: There is a lot in that I don't understand... is there none specific to PUT or POST?

Comment: You do not need to put a try/catch for every single put(). You can put everything into ONE try/catch. That will clean up your code. I know it doesnt fix your issue, however, you can use php to call apis.

Answer (score 1):

just use retrofit 2 for connect to server.
see this [link](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I am aware of retrofit but there is no simple tutorials out there that take you through step by step and I am not quite sure how to go about this

Comment: as far as no simple tutorial..... i found this right away. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845 .   .... stop being lazy

Answer (score 0):

You have an idea in how to do the post petition, but you have a couple of problems. The first and more important problem is that if you want to retrieve information from a server, you must put your code in an async task. You can't do it in UI Thread. So, i'm gonna share with you a class that implements all the logic you need and you just have to use it. First you need to use gson, look how to use it here

https://github.com/google/gson

and the code is here. It have two methods, one for GET and other for POST.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Administrador on 4/27/2017.
 */

public class JsonReaderFromUrl {

    public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int FAILED = 1;
    public static final int PROGRESS = 2;


    public interface OnJesonInterface{
        void OnJsonReceive(int status, JSONObject jsonObject, int key);
    }

    public JsonReaderFromUrl() {
    }

    public void getJsonFromUrlPost(final String url, final OnJesonInterface onJesonInterface, final String body, final int key){
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(PROGRESS,null,0);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
                    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                try {
                    URL urlJson = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) urlJson.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(body);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    connection.connect();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    int httpStatus = connection.getResponseCode();
                    if (httpStatus == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED){
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"utf-8")
                        );
                        String line = "";
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        return stringBuilder.toString();
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                if (s != null){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(SUCCESS,jsonObject,key);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(FAILED,null,0);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void getJsonFromUrl(final String url, final OnJesonInterface onJesonInterface){
        AsyncTask<Void,String,String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(PROGRESS,null,0);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL urlJson = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlJson.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
                        Log.d("RESPONDE JSON: ",">" + line);
                    }
                    return stringBuffer.toString();



                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                if (s != null){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(SUCCESS,jsonObject,0);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else {
                    onJesonInterface.OnJsonReceive(FAILED,null,0);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

import this class where you need and use it PD: The key value is an int that can be used to retrieve what response correspond to each petition, this in case you use this class with a lot of petitions.

Comment: where in this do I send all of my variables?

Comment: In your onClickListener, you create an object of this class and use the methods, in your case getJsonFromUrlPost(), and pass the variables url, the body json in string and implement the interface, you can use just "this" for let the activity or fragment implement the interface. Try to do it, and if you can't i can show you an example.